# How to exclude dependency for Catalyst in Swift Package Manager?

Tags: ios, swift

There is an ios project with Catalyst included. The project has a **YandexMobileMetrica** dependency that cannot compile for mac architecture. How can I add an iOS-only dependency using Swift Package Manager?

I tried to do two targets. In the first **spm-test**, I disabled the mac flag. And in the second, **spm-test-mac** left. My Package.swift looks like this:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "spm-test",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "spm-test",
            targets: ["spm-test"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "YandexMobileMetrica", url: "https://github.com/yandexmobile/metrica-sdk-ios", from: "3.14.1"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "spm-test",
            dependencies: ["YandexMobileMetrica"]),
        .target(
            name: "spm-test-mac",
            dependencies: [])
    ]
)
```

**Error:**

```
AppDelegate.swift:11:12: No such module 'YandexMobileMetrica'
```

**My AppDelegate.swift**

```
//  AppDelegate.swift
//

import UIKit

#if !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    import YandexMobileMetrica //  Error here
#endif
```